# size of size_t preprocessor value

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, c-preprocessor, size-t

I am creating an implementation of a hash table in C for educational purposes.

The hash function should return a size_t hash. Since the size of size_t is different in different platforms (and I want to use a hash function that hashes all the bits in a size_t), I thought of creating different hash functions for different sizes. As the hash function will be used as a function pointer, I suspect the compiler can't inline code like this:

```
size_t hash4(void* key, size_t size);
size_t hash8(void* key, size_t size);

size_t hash(void* key, size_t size)
{
    if (sizeof(size_t) == 4)
    {
        return hash4(key, size);
    }
    else if (sizeof(size_t) == 8)
    {
        return hash8(ket, size);
    }
}

size_t (*hashFunc)(void* key, size_t size) = hash;
```

And two levels of indirection will be used each time the hash function will be called.

That's why I thought of doing something like this: `size_t (*hashFunc)(void* key, size_t size) = hash##sizeof(size_t);` instead. Only one level of indirection will be used. The problem is that the sizeof operator isn't available during the prepossessing phase.

So what would be a good way to define a preprocessor value which will expand to the correct size of size_t in each platform? I guess I could check against predefined macros, but I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: Your hash function might very well return uint32_t that should be enough for any hash-table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
size_t (*hashFunc)(void* key, size_t size) = (sizeof(size_t) == 8) ? hash8 : hash4;
```

There's also nothing wrong with eznme's approach -- write a single function that behaves differently according to the size of `size_t`. Provided that you don't need the `hash4` function for other purposes on 64bit implementations, of course.

Regarding the title of the question -- if you absolutely need to know about `size_t` at preprocessor time, then use the `SIZE_MAX` macro from `stdint.h`.

Comment: Apparently, I can use it to initialize constant function pointers inside a structure, so I guess I prefer this one actually.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` is a C-operator. `##` is a preprocessor operator. The latter does not know anything about the former.

So you might be better of using a macro referring to the system's bit-width used for addressing, like for example testing like so:

```
#if UINTPTR_MAX == 0xffffffffffffffff
/* it's 64bits pointers */
#elif UINTPTR_MAX == 0xffffffff
/* it's 32bits pointers */
#endif
```

Comment: I know I can't use sizeof as a preprocessor operator (I wrote that). Anyway, I like this solution and I think I'll just use it together with what eznme suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 64-bit detecting macro like defined for many compilers, e.g. GCC uses `__x86_64`

```
size_t hash(void* key, size_t size) {
   #ifdef __x86_64
       compute 64bit hash
   #else
       compute 32bit hash
   #endif
}
```

Comment: For that matter, if you write `if (sizeof(size_t) == 8)` then with any level of optimization the emitted code won't actually perform the test, and the compiler will eliminate whichever branch is dead. You do need both branches to compile, though.

Answer (score 1):

> So what would be a good way to define a preprocessor value which will expand to the correct size of size_t in each platform?

According to the [Glibc manual | Width of an Integer Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Width-of-Type.html):

> TS 18661-1:2014 defines macros for the width of integer types (the
>   number of value and sign bits). One benefit of these macros is they
>   can be used in #if preprocessor directives, whereas sizeof cannot. The
>   following macros are defined in limits.h.
>
> ```
> CHAR_WIDTH
> SCHAR_WIDTH
> UCHAR_WIDTH
> SHRT_WIDTH
> USHRT_WIDTH
> INT_WIDTH
> UINT_WIDTH
> LONG_WIDTH
> ULONG_WIDTH
> LLONG_WIDTH
> ULLONG_WIDTH
> ```
>
> These are the widths of the types char, signed char, unsigned char,
>   short int, unsigned short int, int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned
>   long int, long long int and unsigned long long int, respectively.
>
> Further such macros are defined in stdint.h. Apart from those for
>   types specified by width (see Integers), the following are defined:
>
> ```
> INTPTR_WIDTH
> UINTPTR_WIDTH
> PTRDIFF_WIDTH
> SIG_ATOMIC_WIDTH
> SIZE_WIDTH
> WCHAR_WIDTH
> WINT_WIDTH
> ```
>
> These are the widths of the types intptr_t, uintptr_t, ptrdiff_t,
>   sig_atomic_t, size_t, wchar_t and wint_t, respectively.

According to the manual `SIZE_WIDTH` is what you are looking for.

I'm not sure of the availability with compilers like MSVC, XLC and SunCC; or platforms like AIX, OX X, Solaris or Windows.

Comment: IBM XLC for Linux defines `__SIZE_WIDTH__` in stdint.h. Also, both [XLC for Linux](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSXVZZ_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp161.lelinux.doc/compiler_ref/macros_general.html) and [XLC for AIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlcpp1313.aix.doc/compiler_ref/macros_general.html) define `__SIZE_TYPE__` in stdint.h

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits.h>

size_t hash4(void* key, size_t size);
size_t hash8(void* key, size_t size);

size_t hash(void* key, size_t size)
{
    #if SIZE_MAX == UINT32_MAX
            return hash4(key, size);
    #elif SIZE_MAX == UINT64_MAX
            return hash8(ket, size);
    #else
            static_assert(false, "Not implemented.");
    #endif
}
```

**References**

- [Numeric limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)
- [Fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)